# why does pickle file of fbprophet model need so much memory on hard drive?

Tags: python, pandas, pickle, facebook-prophet

I created a simple fbprophet model with the [airpassengers data](https://github.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/blob/master/airline-passengers.csv):

I created a simple fbprophet model with the airpassengers data:

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from fbprophet import Prophet
import sys

df = pd.read_csv("airline-passengers.csv")

# preprocess columns as fbprophet expects it
df.rename(columns={"Month": "ds", "Passengers": "y"}, inplace=True)
df["ds"] = pd.to_datetime(df["ds"])

m = Prophet()
m.fit(df)
```

However, when I save the object `m`:

```
with open("p_model", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(m, f)
```

it needs >1 MB of memory on my hard drive. The object `m` itself seems to be rather small, as `sys.getsizeof(m)` returns `56`.

Why is the pickle file so large? Is there a suitable alternative for saving the the object for later reuse? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the link of @Kohelet, I found the solultion, it was the `stan_backend` attribute:

```
m.stan_backend = None
```

This reduced the filesize on hard drive to around 18 KB.

Im am still wondering why this is not visible when invoking `sys.sizeof(m)`

Answer (score 1):

I think that it pickles training data also, so try not to save model.history and it should be fine.

Here is nice discussion: https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1159

Comment: Setting the `history` attribute to `0` (something not-`None`, as proposed in your link) did not solve the issue. The pickle file still needs >1 MB (though a tiny bit less) on the hard drive. Also I should note that the training data only needs around 3 KB of memory on the hard drive.

Comment: Have You tried to save everything else than model.history?

Comment: I did. the `stan_backend ` attributed caused the large filesize